# Как в PyQt5 между классами реализуется передача значений переменных?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qt-designer

Как в *PyQt5* реализуются связи между окнами? В случае если оба окна это разные классы, т.е. в *Qt Designer* созданные **два** разных **`.ui`** файла. Язык *Python*.

Имеется 2 окна.
В первом окне (**identification.py**) имеется кнопка "ввод кривой разгона". При нажатии на кнопку открывается окно **vvod.py**, где я вывожу какое-либо число (с помощью кнопки).

Данное число должно передаться в функцию `samovirav`, в окне (**identification.py**).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**identification.py**

```html
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from vvod import Vvod
import sys
import scipy
from scipy import integrate
from control.matlab import *
import control
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
import scipy.optimize as opt

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setEnabled(True)
        MainWindow.resize(413, 212)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(218, 218, 218);")
        MainWindow.setDocumentMode(False)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.rB1 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.rB1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 60, 221, 20))
        self.rB1.setObjectName("rB1")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 30, 181, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 150, 247, 16))
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.line_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 39, 20, 121))
        self.line_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.VLine)
        self.line_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_2.setObjectName("line_2")
        self.line_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 39, 20, 121))
        self.line_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.VLine)
        self.line_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_3.setObjectName("line_3")
        self.line_4 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 30, 247, 16))
        self.line_4.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line_4.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_4.setObjectName("line_4")
        self.rB2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.rB2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 90, 221, 20))
        self.rB2.setObjectName("rB2")
        self.rB3 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.rB3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 120, 221, 20))
        self.rB3.setObjectName("rB3")
        self.pB_raschet = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pB_raschet.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 170, 171, 28))
        self.pB_raschet.setObjectName("pB_raschet")
        self.pB_close = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pB_close.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 170, 71, 28))
        self.pB_close.setObjectName("pB_close")
        self.pB_close.clicked.connect ( MainWindow.close )
        self.pB_raschet_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pB_raschet_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 170, 131, 28))
        self.pB_raschet_2.setObjectName("pB_raschet_2")
        self.rB1.raise_()
        self.line_2.raise_()
        self.line_3.raise_()
        self.line_4.raise_()
        self.label.raise_()
        self.rB2.raise_()
        self.rB3.raise_()
        self.line.raise_()
        self.pB_raschet.raise_()
        self.pB_close.raise_()
        self.pB_raschet_2.raise_()
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Идентификация объекта"))
        MainWindow.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><br/></p></body></html>"))
        self.rB1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Объект с самовыравниванием"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Тип разгонной характеристики"))
        self.rB2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Объект без самовыравнивания"))
        self.rB3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Колебательный"))
        self.pB_raschet.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Расчет коэффициентов"))
        self.pB_close.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Закрыть"))
        self.pB_raschet_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ввод кривой разгона"))

class MainWindow ( QtWidgets.QMainWindow , Ui_MainWindow ) :
    def __init__(self) :
        super ().__init__ ()
        self.setupUi ( self )

        self.pB_raschet_2.clicked.connect ( self.openWindow )
        self.pB_raschet.clicked.connect ( self.RB )

        self.mainWindow = Vvod()


    def openWindow(self) :
        self.mainWindow = Vvod ()
        self.mainWindow.show ()
        self.mainWindow.lineEdit.setText ( "1" )

    def samovirav(self) :

        x_points = [0 , 0.4 , 0.8 , 1.2 , 1.6 , 2.0 , 2.4 , 2.8 , 3.2 , 3.6]
        y_points = [0.00 , 0.11 , 0.36 , 0.61 , 0.79 , 0.89 , 0.94 , 0.98 , 0.99 , 1]

        K = ((y_points[-1] - y_points[0]) / self.Vvod.kp())


    def RB(self) :
        if self.rB1.isChecked () :
            self.samovirav ()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow ()
    w.show ()
    sys.exit ( app.exec_ () )
```

**vvod.py**

```html
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Vvod(object):
    def setupUi(self, Vvod):
        Vvod.setObjectName("Vvod")
        Vvod.resize(374, 413)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Vvod)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 20, 113, 22))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Vvod)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 20, 141, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Vvod)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 50, 93, 28))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.retranslateUi(Vvod)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Vvod)

    def retranslateUi(self, Vvod):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Vvod.setWindowTitle(_translate("Vvod", "Dialog"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Vvod", "Входное воздействие"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Vvod", "PushButton"))

class Vvod ( QtWidgets.QMainWindow , Ui_Vvod ) :
    def __init__(self) :
        super ().__init__ ()
        self.setupUi ( self )

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect ( self.kp )  # +++
        #self.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.kp)

    def kp(self) :
        kp = self.lineEdit.text()
        print(kp)
        return kp


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Vvod ()
    w.show ()
    sys.exit ( app.exec_ () )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы создали объект `self.mainWindow = Vvod()` - все, с ним и работайте.

И не понял зачем вам кнопка `self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Vvod", "PushButton"))` ?

**identification.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from vvod import Vvod
import sys
import scipy
from scipy import integrate
from control.matlab import *
import control
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
import scipy.optimize as opt


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setEnabled(True)
        MainWindow.resize(413, 212)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(218, 218, 218);")
        MainWindow.setDocumentMode(False)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.rB1 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.rB1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 60, 221, 20))
        self.rB1.setObjectName("rB1")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 30, 181, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 150, 247, 16))
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.line_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 39, 20, 121))
        self.line_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.VLine)
        self.line_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_2.setObjectName("line_2")
        self.line_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 39, 20, 121))
        self.line_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.VLine)
        self.line_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_3.setObjectName("line_3")
        self.line_4 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 30, 247, 16))
        self.line_4.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line_4.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_4.setObjectName("line_4")
        self.rB2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.rB2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 90, 221, 20))
        self.rB2.setObjectName("rB2")
        self.rB3 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.rB3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 120, 221, 20))
        self.rB3.setObjectName("rB3")
        self.pB_raschet = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pB_raschet.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 170, 171, 28))
        self.pB_raschet.setObjectName("pB_raschet")
        self.pB_close = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pB_close.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 170, 71, 28))
        self.pB_close.setObjectName("pB_close")
        self.pB_close.clicked.connect ( MainWindow.close )
        self.pB_raschet_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pB_raschet_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 170, 131, 28))
        self.pB_raschet_2.setObjectName("pB_raschet_2")
        self.rB1.raise_()
        self.line_2.raise_()
        self.line_3.raise_()
        self.line_4.raise_()
        self.label.raise_()
        self.rB2.raise_()
        self.rB3.raise_()
        self.line.raise_()
        self.pB_raschet.raise_()
        self.pB_close.raise_()
        self.pB_raschet_2.raise_()
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Идентификация объекта"))
        MainWindow.setToolTip(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><br/></p></body></html>"))
        self.rB1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Объект с самовыравниванием"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Тип разгонной характеристики"))
        self.rB2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Объект без самовыравнивания"))
        self.rB3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Колебательный"))
        self.pB_raschet.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Расчет коэффициентов"))
        self.pB_close.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Закрыть"))
        self.pB_raschet_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ввод кривой разгона"))

class MainWindow ( QtWidgets.QMainWindow , Ui_MainWindow ) :
    def __init__(self) :
        super ().__init__ ()
        self.setupUi ( self )
        self.pB_raschet_2.clicked.connect ( self.openWindow )
        self.pB_raschet.clicked.connect ( self.RB )

        self.mainWindow = Vvod()

    def openWindow(self) :
#?        self.mainWindow = Vvod ()
        self.mainWindow.show()
        self.mainWindow.lineEdit.setText("1")

    def samovirav(self) :
        x_points = [0 , 0.4 , 0.8 , 1.2 , 1.6 , 2.0 , 2.4 , 2.8 , 3.2 , 3.6]
        y_points = [0.00 , 0.11 , 0.36 , 0.61 , 0.79 , 0.89 , 0.94 , 0.98 , 0.99 , 1]

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        kp = self.mainWindow.kp()                                 # !!! self.mainWindow
        if kp:
            print(f'kp = {kp}')
#        K = ((y_points[-1] - y_points[0]) / self.Vvod.kp())
            K = (y_points[-1] - y_points[0]) / float(kp)
            print(f'K = {K}') 
        else:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(
                self, 'Внимание', 'Введите Входное воздействие.')
            
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.mainWindow.close()
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    def RB(self):
        if self.rB1.isChecked():
            self.samovirav()

   

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow ()
    w.show ()
    sys.exit ( app.exec_ () )
```

**vvod.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Vvod(object):
    def setupUi(self, Vvod):
        Vvod.setObjectName("Vvod")
        Vvod.resize(374, 413)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Vvod)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 20, 113, 22))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Vvod)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 20, 141, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Vvod)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 50, 93, 28))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.retranslateUi(Vvod)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Vvod)

    def retranslateUi(self, Vvod):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Vvod.setWindowTitle(_translate("Vvod", "Dialog"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Vvod", "Входное воздействие"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Vvod", "PushButton"))

class Vvod ( QtWidgets.QMainWindow , Ui_Vvod ) :
    def __init__(self) :
        super ().__init__ ()
        self.setupUi ( self )

#        self.pushButton.clicked.connect ( self.kp )                        # ???    
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.hide)
        #self.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.kp)

    def kp(self) :
        kp = self.lineEdit.text()
        print(kp)
        return kp


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Vvod ()
    w.show ()
    sys.exit ( app.exec_ () )
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]